# How to implement AspNetCore.Identity with windows authentication with custom roles?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using Asp.NET Core 2 with EF (Code First)
I don't want to use the existing AD groups but want custom roles for each user. Also if user has no roles add "Member" role because no anonymous login is enabled. 
Is there an easy way to do this using Identity?

Comment: No, because Identity and Windows Auth are mutually exclusive. If you want to use Identity *and* sync with AD, you'll need to implement a manual LDAP connection to handle that. However, that's far beyond the scope of Stack Overflow, so you'll need to do your own research and attempt a solution.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Is there a method you suggest for Role and Authorization for Windows Authentication?